# How do you use %random% to pick a numbered variable?

Tags: batch-file

I want to use `%random% %%118` to pick a random variable from a number of variables called "song1" through "song118" Here's my current code:

```
@ECHO off
TITLE Music Randomize
SET count=0
GOTO cont

:func
ECHO %1
SET /A count+=1
SET "song%count%=%1"
GOTO :eof

:cont
FOR %%F IN (C:\Users\153651\Desktop\usic\*) DO CALL :func "%%F"

ECHO %song%random% %%118 +1%
PAUSE
```

Right now the last ECHO command gives me the output `"random18 +1"`. How can I get it to output a random one of the variables?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few minor errors in your code:

- Arithmetic works only with `set /a`, so you need to pre-calculate the value before using it
- you should use `%~1` to remove the quotes
- to use a "variable within a variable", you need either [delayed expansion or another trick to force a second instance of parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) (I decided not to use delayed expansion, because there might be `!` in your files (think `P!nk` for example))

The corrected code could look like this:

```
@ECHO off
setlocal 
TITLE Music Randomize
SET count=0
GOTO cont

:func
rem ECHO %1
SET /A count+=1
SET "song%count%=%~1"
GOTO :eof

:cont
FOR %%F IN (C:\Users\153651\Desktop\usic\*) DO CALL :func "%%F"
set /a rnd=%random% %%118 +1
call ECHO %%song%rnd%%%
pause
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm a little confused by what your problem is.

As an example, this works:

```
set SONG=TaylorSwift

REM Choose a random number between 1 and 118
set /a SONGNUM=%RANDOM% * 118 / 32768 + 1

REM Here's the random song name:
set MYSONG=%SONG%%SONGNUM%
echo %MYSONG%

REM Prints: TaylorSwift9 (if "9" was the random number)
```

I think you might have a mismatch in how your `%` signs are aligned, but I'm struggling to understand the aims of your code.